# Whats the right way to go back with nested pages in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

**How do you properly go back with out passing named params, and with out using url->previous**

For example with `url()->previous()`:

1. If you refresh the page, any `url()->previous()` does not work on that page.
2. If you go from `route/1` -> `apples/1` -> `bananas/2` -> back to, using `url()->previous()` `apples/1` and have `url()->previous()` on `apples/1`  it will take you back to `bananas/2` not back back to `route/1`

*People know this*. The only possible solution is to **use named routes**, in this case I would have to pass the `apples` route id to `bananas/` to go back to `apples/1`, I would also have to use a named route on `route/1` and pass its route param from `apples/1` to the named route to go back.

This isn't an issue until you have pages that go deep and nothing related to each other model wise:

- /route/1 - Separate Controller and Model

  - leads to: `/apples/1` - Separate Controller and Model

    - leads to: `/someOtherRoute/2` - Separate Controller and Model

      - leads to: ... and so on ... - Separate Controller and Model

If you use `url()->previous()`, because *I think its session based*, and I use a database for sessions, it doesn't remember where you were going, it legit works on the previous url as the chain suggests.

So when you have nested pages like this where nothing is related, how do you handle: **going back one at a time? (that is clicking the back button to traverse the chain back to `route/1`)** are you legit passing all the params through to each controller action?

Are you using request? so all your urls now look like: `/apples/1/?route=1` ???:

```
    route('apples.apple', [
        'apple' => $apple->id
        'route' => $route->id // => ?route=1
    ]);
```

*Whats the laravel way to go back on routes that do not relate to each-other*.

Its one thing if it was `route/1/apples/1/SomeOtherRoute/2`, because that, to me, shows a direct relation, how ever in the above example, these are all separate routes, with their own controllers and actions and their models do not relate to each-other.

The only way they relate is by starting on `route/1` and clicking into `apples/1` and then clicking into ... and so on and so forth. Each page having its own back button.

Comment: `url()->previous()` uses the header information stored within `referrer`. PHP code is `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`  , meaning the page that brought you to the page you are currently on will be the page you go back to. So if you refresh the current page, then it will go back to the current page because your current header information reffer is your current url. You can try with js `onclick="window.history.back()"`

Comment: @sta if you read the docs on window.history.back(), its the same as clicking the back button, so this would not solve the problem. It would just shift it over to JS.

Comment: Then you can do that with session

Comment: @sta care to answer the question with an example? So I can mark this as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things but this was the only solution I found for my use case when using nested pages with back buttons:

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()"</a>
```